# Javascript array concatenation

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have three variables a, b and c. I have to insert these into an array called `arr`. On calling function click, these variables should get pushed into `arr` array. eg. if i call click with arg 1,2 & 3 then array should be [1,2,3], now when I will pass the args 6,7 then the array should be [1,2,3,6,7].
In the code below, I tried to use `concat` method to get the desired result but i was unsuccessful.Is there any way around this?

```js
function click(a,b,c){

    var A=a;
    var B=b;
    var C=c;

    var arr=[]
    var newArr=[A,B,C]
    arr.concat(newArr);
    console.log(arr);

}

click(10,11,12);
click(12,13,14);
```

Comment: you should declare the variable 'arr' outside the function click

Comment: you can use arr.push(newArr); Its another way to insert into an array.

Comment: Still didn't work ":(

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed i am getting [ [ 10, 11, 12 ], [ 12, 13, 14 ] ] ... not [10,11,12,12,13,14]  :(

Comment: you can do arr.push(a, b, c) also, you dont need to assign them to another variable or array.

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed, arr.push(newArr) just add an newArr as one element to arr. So arr will be something like [[a,b,c]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a global array outside of the function and then after push values into it.

```js
var arr = [];
function click(a,b,c){
    arr.push(a, b, c)
}

click(10,11,12);
click(12,13,14);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that, you are concatenating to the array but not considering the return value.

```
arr = arr.concat(newArr);
```

Then declare the array global to hold the values for every click.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function click(arr, a, b, c){
    arr.push(a, b, c);
    console.log(arr);
}

var arr = [];
click(arr, 10, 11, 12);
click(arr, 12, 13, 14);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your `arr` outside your function, another approach is storing your `arr` inside `click` **scope** then call it anywhere (it doesn't pollute your **global scope**):

```js
    let click = (function (arr) {
       return function (a,b,c) {
    
        var A=a;
        var B=b;
        var C=c;
    
        var newArr=[A,B,C]
        arr = arr.concat(newArr);
        console.log(arr);
      }
    })([])

    click(10,11,12);
    click(12,13,14);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You should either define `arr` outside your function or pass `arr` into function as a parameter. 
Second one. Function `concat` returns concatenated arrays and left original arrays unchanged. So you need something like `arr=arr.concat(newArr)`

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem here is that the concat function returns a new array instance with the elements:
[Check Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
    function click(a,b,c){

        var A=a;
        var B=b;
        var C=c;

        var arr=[]
        var newArr=[A,B,C]
        arr = arr.concat(newArr);
        // concat does not change the ref itself
        console.log(arr);

    }

click(10,11,12);
click(12,13,14);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) can be used to functionally `concatenate` 
`variables` with `arrays`.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const input = [1, 2, 3]

// Click.
const click = (array, ...arguments) => [...array, ...arguments]

// Output.
const output = click(input, 4, 5, 6)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```